# How to get a user's hashed password and hashed salt from firebase authentication onCreate trigger?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access a user's hashed password and hashed salt using onCreate authentication trigger but I always got null values for both of them, however I am getting the other user's values normally.

```
exports.savePasswordsInfo = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  functions.logger.log("hash: ",user.passwordHash);
  functions.logger.log("salt: ",user.passwordSalt);
  functions.logger.log(user)
});
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the definition of those properties, it says:

1. If no password is set, this is null.
2. This is only available when the user is obtained from `listUsers()`.

Are the new users created using email-password auth? Even if yes, that `user` object will have those values as null. You can read more about this in the following Github issue:

[Why is passwordHash and passwordSalt only available with listUsers()?](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/408)

---

If you want to store user's password in Firestore as well then you can  create the user in a Cloud Function itself:

```
exports.createUser= functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // 1. Read user email and pass from data
  // 2. Store the information in Firestore
  // 3. Create a user in Firebase Auth
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to get the user's password, hash it and then store it in Cloud Firestore, and I don't want to do all this work in the sign-up method. And since I can't do it using the onCreate trigger, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: @AliOz you can then just do all the processing in a Cloud function itself instead of using Firebase client SDKs to create users.